# Random "No input files specified" in Nginx and php-fpm

Tags: nginx, php

I recently starts using Nginx with php-fpm. Everything seems alright except occasionally I am getting "No input file specified" and a 404 logged in the access.log. It appears random where one request getting an 200 while another request to the same file getting 404 with the above error. No related errors found in both Nginx and php-fpm error.log.

Here's an extract of the access.log:

```
10.0.0.5 - - [09/Aug/2011:18:14:27 -0400]  200 "POST /services/ChangeAccount HTTP/1.1" 110 "http://slotspot-internal.blitzoo.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:5.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/5.0" "94.49.122.184"
10.0.0.5 - - [09/Aug/2011:18:15:27 -0400]  404 "POST /services/ChangeAccount HTTP/1.1" 36 "http://slotspot-internal.blitzoo.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:5.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/5.0" "94.49.122.184"
10.0.0.5 - - [09/Aug/2011:18:15:28 -0400]  200 "POST /services/ChangeAccount HTTP/1.1" 110 "http://slotspot-internal.blitzoo.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:5.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/5.0" "94.49.122.184"
```

Have done some research and made sure the document root is defined in Nginx configuration server block and fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME is defined as $document_root$fastcgi_script_name

Here's my nginx.conf:

```
user       nginx nginx;
worker_processes  5;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;
worker_rlimit_nofile 8192;

events {
  worker_connections  4096;
}

http {
  include    /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  include    /etc/nginx/proxy.conf;
  include    /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
  index    index.html index.htm index.php;

  default_type application/octet-stream;
  log_format   main '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local]  $status '
    '"$request" $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
  access_log   /var/log/nginx/access.log main;
  sendfile     on;
  tcp_nopush   on;
  server_names_hash_bucket_size 128; # this seems to be required for some vhosts


  server {
     listen       80;
     server_name  _;
     root   /opt/myapp/current/server/public;

     location / {
         root   /opt/myapp/current/server/public;
         index  index.php index.html index.htm;
     }

     error_page  404         /404.html;
     location = /404.html {
         root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
     }

     # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
     #
     error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
     location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
     }

     # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
     # concurs with nginx's one
     #
     location ~ /\.ht {
         deny  all;
     }

     location ~ /admin {
     rewrite   ^/admin(.*)$ /router.php last;
     }
     location ~ /index/ {
     rewrite   ^/index/(.*)$ /router.php last;
     }
     location ~ /services/ {
     rewrite   ^/services/(.*)$ /router.php last;
     }
     location ~ /skupdater/ {
     rewrite   ^/skupdater/(.*)$ /router.php last;
     }

     location ~ \.php$ {
     root           /opt/myapp/current/server/public;
     fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
     fastcgi_index  index.php;
     include        fastcgi_params;
     fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
     fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO $fastcgi_script_name;
     }

  }
}
```

Thanks everyone in advance.

Answer (score 6):

This can happen when PHP-FPM tries to open the PHP file, hits the rlimit about open files and returns a 404.

Here are the relevant parts of an strace ([complete strace output](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=PVCqF9cD)) :

```
open("/home/julien/www/shape/engine/index.php", O_RDONLY) = -1 EMFILE (Too many open files)
write(4, "\1\6\0\1\0d\4\0Status: 404 Not Found\r\nX"..., 128) = 128
```

So you can edit your rlimit_files or your system configuration to let PHP-FPM open more files.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and found this hint in the logs:

```
open_basedir restriction in effect
```

So what I did to get it working is to add the folder where phpmyadmin sits to the list in `php.ini`.

Comment: Had similar problem here. Your tip sure helped me. Thanks

Comment: Thank you very much, was turned off in `php.ini`, but my `/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/domainname.conf` was over riding the setting.

Answer (score 0):

I have been running into the same issue, and I have found out that the solution is the same as for https://superuser.com/questions/787888/too-many-files-open-on-mac-osx-after-running-apache-in-php-with-xdebug-for-som

There's a bug in xdebug which doesn't close the file correctly, so you are hitting a limit. If you deactivate the remote debugging this error doesn't appear anymore.

For now I have set `xdebug.remote_enable`to on and `xdebug.remote_autostart`to off, in case I want to debug something I am activating the debugger with this handy chrome extension: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xdebug-helper/eadndfjplgieldjbigjakmdgkmoaaaoc